# Tabbed Input in html and css

Tags: php, html, css

I have a query regarding web development using html and css and here it goes:

I have created a horizontal tabbed input using html and css. The URL for accessing this page is http://example.com/tabbedInput.html. The user see a row of tabs and there is a huge space below the horizontal tab bar. Now, when the user clicks on one of the tabs, i will have to draw various html components into this space. Could any body let me know how can i achieve this? I mean, drawing the components in the same web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to effect tabs and it depends on several factors which you choose.

If you have lightweight content that needs to be segregated you can simply output ALL of the tabs' content HTML, hiding all but the selected tab. To do that you would need to observe the tab links and act appropriately.

However, if you have content on each tabs that requires queries to build or heavy processing, you wouldn't want to output all the tabs at once, but you might use AJAX to load the contents of each tab on click.

EDIT: Example

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
function showTabs(currentTab) {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab_content');
    if (tabs.length == 0) {
    return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if(tabs[i].id != currentTab) {
            tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            tabs[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    showTabs('general');
    document.getElementById('general_link').onclick = function() { showTabs('general'); return false; };
    document.getElementById('special_link').onclick = function() { showTabs('special'); return false; };
};
// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="general_link" href="javascript:void()">General</a> &nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp; <a id="special_link" href="javascript:void()">Special</a>

<div id="general" class="tab_content">
    general contents
</div>

<div id="special" class="tab_content">
    special contents
</div>
</body>
</html>
```